# Dynamic forms with MVVM, DomainCollectionView, etc

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Greetings.

I'm using an Entity Data Model with a LinqToEntities DomainService. In my ViewModel, I'm using the new SP1 DomainCollectionView to Bind my datagrid itemssource. Currently, that looks like this:

```
this._source = new EntityList<P_BUDGET>(this._context.P_BUDGETs);
this._loader = new DomainCollectionViewLoader<P_BUDGET>(
             this.LoadSampleEntities,
             this.OnLoadSampleEntitiesCompleted);
this._view = new DomainCollectionView<P_BUDGET>(this._loader, this._source);
```

I then have a property, called CollectionView, bound to the ItemsSource of my grid. The Prop looks like this: `public ICollectionView CollectionView { get { return this._view; }}`  My ideal endgame would be to have a left menu with a list of 15 different items. Each item would correspond to an entity in my Data Model (e.g. Budgets). When a user clicked on Budgets, I'd resolve that to the entity P_BUDGET, and pass it through to a service that called my data, returned my _view, which would bind my gridview. If a user clicked on "Accounts", it would return the P_ACCOUNTS data, etc etc. Essentially, dynamic maintenance pages.

I've googled the hell outta this, and I'm simply not sure what i should be searching for. I'm new to most of this!

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?  I wanted to be sure, since MVVM is a pattern only used with WPF.  Also which MVVM framework are you using?  If none, then you would be better off to select one as a starting point.

Comment: Hey sorry, I'm using Silverlight with MVVM-Light